# safari 5.1.9 snow leopard

Tags: html, css, osx-snow-leopard, safari

I have a client who came to me due to issues with their navigation display on Safari 5.1.9 on Snow Leopard. The navigation shows just find on all other browsers, but on Safari 5.1.9 (Snow Leopard only), it shows temporarily and then disappears.

Originally, I made this fix: removing relative & absolute positioning in the below code. However, that in fact breaks the rest of the site (Twitter widget disappears, Slider formatting is out of sorts, etc).

Any ideas on how else to resolve this issue without messing up the rest of the site?

Thanks for your help! Let me know if I can provide any more information.

```
div.navigation-wrapper {
position: absolute;
top: 0px;
left: 0px;
right: 0px;
z-index: 101;
border-top-width: 1px;
border-bottom-width: 1px;
border-style: solid;
font-family: HelveticaNeue, "Helvetica Neue", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

div.gdl-navigation-wrapper {
position: relative;
z-index: 101;
min-height: 53px;
}
```

Comment: You need to provide some code that demonstrates the problem. Without any context, how do you expect people to help you?

Answer (score 0):

This might be your issue:

```
div.navigation-wrapper {
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    right: 0px;
}
```

You should only specify either left or right values, not both. Also, I don't really know because there is no way to test my code because you have not given us much context, as Barmar noted.